# Searching an arraylist for username and password

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, awt

I am creating a login window for a program. I am having trouble getting my program to search through my arraylist and return a username and then search again for a password.

```
    public class Login extends JFrame {

    public String firstName, lastName, account, birthYear, password;
    Login(String fn, String ln, String acc, String by, String pw){
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        account = acc;
        birthYear = by;
        password = pw;
    }
    Login current;

    ArrayList<Login> list= new ArrayList<Login>();
    int count;

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private final Action action = new SwingAction();
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login frame = new Login();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Login() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setBounds(217, 5, 212, 126);
        contentPane.add(label);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                    if (Arrays.equals(list.get(i).password.toCharArray(), textField.getText().toCharArray())){
                        System.out.println("found the account");
                        if (Arrays.equals(list.get(i).password.toCharArray(), passwordField.getPassword())){

                            current = list.get(i);

                            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        overview frame = new overview();
                                        frame.setVisible(true);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password does not match our records", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account number not found", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }

            }
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setAction(action);
        btnLogin.setBounds(108, 186, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLogin);

        JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
        btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Register frame = new Register();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        btnRegister.setBounds(217, 186, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnRegister);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(172, 148, 142, 20);
        contentPane.add(passwordField);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel.setBounds(39, 32, 335, 51);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        JLabel lblLogin = new JLabel("Login");
        lblLogin.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));
        panel.add(lblLogin);
        lblLogin.setForeground(SystemColor.window);
        lblLogin.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JLabel lblAccountNumber = new JLabel("Account Number:");
        lblAccountNumber.setBounds(49, 101, 113, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAccountNumber);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:\r\n");
        lblPassword.setBounds(49, 151, 113, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblPassword);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(172, 98, 142, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
    }
    public void printLogin(Login l) {
        System.out.println(l.firstName);
        System.out.println(l.lastName);
        System.out.println(l.account);
        System.out.println(l.birthYear);
        System.out.println(l.password);
    }
    private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SwingAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Login");
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Login to your account");
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to run the program when the "Login" button is pressed but it currently isn't working.

Comment: where's your `main()` method or how you are invoking this class?

Answer (score 2):

Below line has a problem :

```
if (list.get(i).password.equals(passwordField.getPassword())){
```

[JPasswordField#getPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) return `char[]` where as you are comparing a String `password` with `char[]` that is wrong.

Try [Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5b%5d,%20char%5b%5d%29) to compare arrays as follow:

```
Arrays.equals(list.get(i).password.toCharArray(), passwordField.getPassword());
```

---

I suggest you to use `Map` in place of `ArrayList`. Make `username` as key of Map.

Use

```
Map<String,Login> map = new HashMap<String,Login>();
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<Login> list= new ArrayList<Login>();
```

> `Map` is more faster in search than `ArrayList`.

Comment: I definitely agree with this. A map is a far better way to go because you can map a specific password to a specific username.

Comment: But I'm not comparing two arrays, I am comparing a single string to a member variable of type string of an object in an array list. Will look into Map

Comment: What `passwordField.getPassword()` returns?

Comment: Thank you. I believe I understand now. I have made the changes as you have suggested, but it still isn't working. I tried inserting a print method after it found the account but it did not respond. This would suggest there is a problem with 'if (list.get(i).account.contains(textField.getText()))' as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Compiles and runs just fine. When I hit the button, nothing happens

Comment: You are creating multiple `JFrame`s because `Login` extends `JFrame`.  That's wrong. Create a separate POJO class for `Login`.

Comment: `contentPane` is never initialized. You will get null pointer exception.

Comment: You have to think again and redesign as per swing application. For more info look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my notes can be helpful :

1. There is no `main` method to make the class runnable
2. The location of `list.add(test);` is not allowed there. It should be in constructor/method.

Comment: Thank you for those corrections. I have edited the post accordingly.